# Javascript Timer will not change state

Tags: javascript, variables, time, timer

I'm trying to make a timer for this game, that will count down from 30 seconds every 1000 Milliseconds, but when I run the code, the Timer does change; it stays at 30.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var gameTimer = {
    time: 30,
    interval: undefined,
    start: function(time) {
        var self = this;
        this.interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);
    },
    tick: function() {
        this.time = this.time - 1;
    },
    stop: function(time){
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },
    reset: function(){
        this.time = 30;
    }
};
```

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Change from this:

```
this.interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

to this:

```
this.interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
```

The issue is that when you pass `tick` to setInterval, the object reference is lost when `tick()` is called and thus `this` has the wrong value.  You probably end up changing a global variable named `time` because of the wrong `this` value.

Passing `this.tick.bind(this)` causes the `this` pointer to be set properly when `tick()` is called by the interval and thus the `this.time` reference in that method works properly.

FYI, if you were working in strict mode, your error would have been pointed out to you by the runtime because `this` would have been undefined rather than `window` (one of the reasons for strict mode).

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this instead

```
var gameTimer = function() {
    this.time = 30;
    this.interval;

    this.start = function() {
        self = this;
        this.interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
        console.log(this.interval);
    };
    this.tick = function() {
        console.log(this.time);
        this.time = this.time - 1;
    };
    this.stop = function(){
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    };
    this.reset = function(){
        this.time = 30;
    };
};
var timer = new gameTimer();
timer.start();
```

Fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/jL2jc4jr/

In the code example I didn't put the code stopper but I think you can do that from this point on.  Enjoy you game timer.